# typo3 uriBuilder and realurl link

Tags: typo3, extbase

I create link to the page in controller like

```
$uriPage = $this->uriBuilder->reset()->setTargetPageUid(intval($row['page']))->setCreateAbsoluteUri(TRUE)->build();
```

And get http://mydomain.tld/index.php?id=70 But I'm using realurl and need realurl link.
Can I make link like http://mydomain.tld/mypage/ via uriBuilder in Controller?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The script you wrote to generate link is correct but you need to check configuration of realurl(Script will automatically generates that kind of URL)

It can be in TS

```
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

OR

it can be at .htaccess side

OR

you need to check your apache settings that might prevent generation of URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in TYPO3 7.6.2
Configuration is OK,  because the normal navigation is rendered with realurl. Just the URI that I get from uriBuilder is formatted without realurl.

Update: The problem arises when I use setCreateAbsoluteUri(true).
Solution: make the url absolute afterwards.

```
// ...
$this->uriBuilder->setCreateAbsoluteUri(false);
$link = $this->uriBuilder->build();
$uri = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::locationHeaderUrl($link);
```

Comment: May be this should be a comment, or?

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises when the project is not beeing run inside the server root but in some subdirectory and additionally the TypoScript setting `config.absRefPrefix` is not set. 
The reason is, that the underlying typolink core method checks current host domain e.g. **www.example.de** with the requested path e.g. **www.example.de/somesubdirectory**. 
Because in case of missing setting from above they are different, the logic decides, that we are building a cross domain request URI, and any URL beautifier like RealUrl etc. are being skipped. I guess one might consider it as a bug.

So one solution might be to set `config.absRefPrefix`.

As I said above, this problem does not arise if run inside the server root directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this party, but anyway:

If you run into this problem, you might wanna check your typoscript.
There, you need to add

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
```

Then realurl should render the links correctly. If you set it to 1, you end up having the `index.php?id=xxx`

Maybe this helps somebody who ends up here.